# Is using hash function for IDs a good practice?

Tags: java, hash

I have a list of files I have to place inside of a DB where no sequence is provided. This DB has an ID (VARCHAR 256 ) column which has to be unique.

I was wondering if I could handle my IDs in such a way:

```
hash(/completepathtofile/filename + creationdate) --> ID
```

the filepath is unique to each file, while the creation date allows me to even have duplicates of the same file with different dates so to support some kind of versioning.

My idea would be to give this concatenation to an hash function so to generate the ID.
In case a collision should occur I would fallback in this way:

```
hash(/completepathtofile/filename + creationdate + random salt) --> NEW_ID
```

Would this be a good practice? And is there any recommended algorithm to use?

Clearly, the top priority would be an algorithm minimizing collisions while keeping a reasonable speed for performance.

Comment: A **cryptographic** hash would be fine, and the salt wouldn't even be needed. But why not just use a UUID? The hash would be useful if you had to find the ID for a given file path and creation date. If you just want a unique ID, a UUID is just fine, and faster.

Comment: what do you mean with a VARCHAR with 256 bits?

Comment: VARCHAR(256) means not 256 bits, but 256 characters.

Comment: Yes sorry, fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create a **Universally Unique IDentifier (UUID)**.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

> Thus, anyone can create a UUID and use it to identify something with near certainty that the identifier does not duplicate one that has already been, or will be, created to identify something else. Information labeled with UUIDs by independent parties can therefore be later combined into a single database, or transmitted on the same channel, without needing to resolve conflicts between identifiers.

Comment: You mean by using UUID.randomUUID()? Would it be good collision-wide? I thought about hashing functions because 1) I could, in case, obtain the ID starting from the filepath 2) I thought it would have been more robust for collisions

Comment: It's its main purpose. I just updated the answer with a quote from wikipedia and a link to it ;)

Comment: Mmm..is there any way to make the string longer than 64 chars so to be even more confident? The sha512 leads to a 128 long string which should be safer...or not?